# Trigger Jenkins build for each commit on develop branch

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket

I build a freestyle jenkins pipeline that executes sonarqube scanner on develop branch and sends slack notification after the build finishes with the results, when I build the pipeline manually it works as expected.

I used Bitbucket Plugin to trigger the build after each commit, but it's only working after I changed the pipeline to track the master branch instead, and the pipeline is not triggered on develop automatically. I don't know where's the problem exactly.

I'm using ssh access key to connect to my private bitbucket repository, and my webhook is returning 200, thanks for your help.

**Source Code Management**
[image: Source Code Management]

**Build**
[image: Build]

**Build Triggers**
[image: Build Triggers]

**Bitbucket WebHook**
[image: Bitbucket WebHook 1]
[image: Bitbucket WebHook 2]

Answer (score 0):

solved using generic-webhook-trigger https://link.medium.com/NaDci1Hfvfb